# Makefile doesn't choose the right folder to build even though specified

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm new to c++ and struggling to understand why my Makefile does not do the expected.

This is the (desired) structure of my project:

```
MyProject
 ├── build
 │   ├── debug
 │   │   ├── main
 │   │   └── src
 │   │       └── call .o and .d files compiled with debug flag
 │   └── release
 │       ├── main
 │       └── src
 │           └── all .o and .d files compiled without additional flags
 ├── include
 │   └── all .hpp files
 ├── lib
 │   └── currently empty
 ├── src
 │   └── all .cpp files
 └── Makefile
```

The folder structure in the build folder is the desired part - that's the part that doesn't work.
My intention is: whenever I call `make`, it builds the `.o` and `.d` files into the `release` folder following the src folder structure, and the main executable is placed directly in `/release`.
Similarly, whenever I call `make debug` it builds into the `debug` folder (with the additional debug flags being passed).

ATM calling `make` results in this structure:

```
MyProject
 ├── build
 │   ├── main
 │   └── src
 │       └── all .o and .d files compiled without additional flags
...
```

So `make` does not result in the usage of the `release` folder even though `release` should be the default target.

Calling `make debug` (and `make release` if you replace accordingly) result in this structure:

```
MyProject
 ├── build
 │   ├── debug
 │   │   └── main
 │   └── src
 │       └── all .o and .d files (not compiled anew! And hence without the debug flags)
...
```

Only the `main` executable is in the `debug` folder. The rest is under `/build` and not compiled again if I invoked `make` before. Therefore, the debug flags are missing and I don't get my debugging output.
So the build works in general, the files are just not where I want them to be and in case of debug I have to run `make clean` every time to get the right compilation and my debugging output.

I understand that these blocks are called recipe and everything indented with a tab is passed to the shell. I don't think I understand the general execution flow of a Makefile, though.
This part

```
$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(MD) $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -MMD -o $@
```

seems to be executed before anything else. I don't even see from where it is called. Especially this is the part that fails as it does not have the updated `BUILD` path.

This is my full Makefile:

```
CXX         = g++
CXXFLAGS    = -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g
debug: CXXFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
LFLAGS      =

SRC     := src
BUILD       = build
release: BUILD  := $(BUILD)/release
debug: BUILD    := $(BUILD)/debug
INCLUDE     := include
LIB     := lib

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
  MAIN      := main.exe
  SOURCEDIRS    := $(SRC)
  INCLUDEDIRS   := $(INCLUDE)
  LIBDIRS   := $(LIB)
  FIXPATH   = $(subst /,\,$1)
  RM        := del /q /f
  MD        := mkdir
else
  MAIN      := main
  SOURCEDIRS    := $(shell find $(SRC) -type d)
  INCLUDEDIRS   := $(shell find $(INCLUDE) -type d)
  LIBDIRS   := $(shell find $(LIB) -type d)
  FIXPATH   = $1
  RM        := rm -f
  MD        := mkdir -p
endif

INCLUDES        := $(patsubst %,-I%, $(INCLUDEDIRS:%/=%))
LIBS            := $(patsubst %,-L%, $(LIBDIRS:%/=%))
SOURCES         := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%/*.cpp, $(SOURCEDIRS)))
OBJECTS         := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(BUILD)/%.o)
DEPS            := $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)


all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(MD) $(BUILD)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(BUILD)/$(MAIN) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

# this seems to be executed whenever calling any "make" command
# this command does not have the updated BUILD path (aka build/release or build/debug)
# Is this a recipe as well? When is it called?
$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(MD) $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -MMD -o $@

-include $(DEPS)

# I would like for release to be called when simply calling "make" (doesn't happen)
.PHONY: default_target
default_target: release

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(call FIXPATH,$(BUILD)/$(MAIN))
    $(RM) $(call FIXPATH,$(OBJECTS))
    $(RM) $(call FIXPATH,$(DEPS))
    @echo Cleanup complete!

.PHONY: debug
debug: all

.PHONY: release
release: all

.PHONY: debugrun
debugrun: all
    ./$(call FIXPATH,$(BUILD)/$(MAIN))

.PHONY: run
run: all
    ./$(call FIXPATH,$(BUILD)/$(MAIN))
```

*Of course I did not come up with this Makefile on my own. I copied from two templates. My first template built all `.o` and `.d` files into the `src` directory. :/ And consulted various other stackoverflow posts but couldn't crack this last bit. This Makefile has seen much worse stages.*

Comment: Why do you use a makefile in the first place and for example cmake? Is there a specific reason or are you simply not aware of more modern/sophisticated systems?

Comment: *sigh* I really wish someday we would stop with the very first answer to every question being "why don't you do something entirely different instead".  cmake is a good tool but it has its own problems and limitations.  It's not the answer to every question and SO is not the right place to have philosophical discussions about which tools are appropriate for which tasks.  Let's just answer the question that was asked.

Comment: I don't think that a build _configuration_ system is a reasonable substitute for a build system in the first place. Especially one I'd characterise as "overcomplicated" rather than "sophisticated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way Make works, you cannot do this with regular targets alone.
You would expect `make debug release` to build both flavors of your program, yet any approach that sets variables will see only one flavor being built.

## Approach 1: recursive Make

One way to do it is by using a recursive invocation of make:

```
all: debug

BUILD_DIR=build
BUILD_TYPE ?= unknown
BUILD_PREFIX=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(BUILD_TYPE)
TARGETS=main

SOURCES := src/foo.cpp
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(BUILD_PREFIX)/%.o)
DEPS    := $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),0)

release:
        $(MAKE) BUILD_TYPE=release
debug:
        $(MAKE) BUILD_TYPE=debug

else

release: $(addprefix $(BUILD_PREFIX)/, $(TARGETS))
debug: $(addprefix $(BUILD_PREFIX)/, $(TARGETS))

$(BUILD_PREFIX)/main: $(OBJECTS) | $(BUILD_PREFIX)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(BUILD_PREFIX):
        mkdir -p $(BUILD_PREFIX)

$(BUILD_PREFIX)/%.o: %.cpp
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -MMD -o $@

-include $(DEPS)

endif
```

The key bit here is that `$(MAKELEVEL)` is set to 0 on the outer invocation of make, and to 1 on the recursive invocation. In the former case we define the release and debug targets to do a recursive invocation with `BUILD_TYPE` explicitly set.

The only other notable fact is the use of `|` in the prerequisites list of `$(BUILD_PREFIX)/main`. This is only used for ordering but does not show up in `$@`.

## Approach 2: code generation

You can also keep everything in a single Make invocation but make use of macro expansion to avoid repeating yourself:

```
all: debug      
                                

TARGETS=main              
                       
BUILD_DIR = build  
SOURCES := src/foo.cpp
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
DEPS    := $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)                                            
     
CXXFLAGS_debug := -DDEBUG -Og -g   
CXXFLAGS_release := -DRELEASE -O2 

define build_flavor
$(eval BUILD_TYPE=$1)
$(eval BUILD_PREFIX=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(BUILD_TYPE))                        
$(BUILD_TYPE): $(addprefix $(BUILD_PREFIX)/, $(TARGETS))               
$(BUILD_PREFIX)/main: $(addprefix $(BUILD_PREFIX)/, $(OBJECTS)) | $(BUILD_PREFIX)
        $$(CXX) $$(CXXFLAGS_$(BUILD_TYPE)) $$(INCLUDES) -o $$@ $$^ $$(LDFLAGS) $$(LIBS)

$(BUILD_PREFIX):
        mkdir -p $(BUILD_PREFIX)

$(BUILD_PREFIX)/%.o: %.cpp
        mkdir -p $$(@D)
        $$(CXX) $$(CXXFLAGS_$(BUILD_TYPE)) $$(INCLUDES) -c $$< -MMD -o $$@

-include $(addprefix $(BUILD_PREFIX)/, $(DEPS))                        
endef
$(eval $(call build_flavor, debug))
$(eval $(call build_flavor, release))
```

Note the doubled-up dollar signs `$$` for some variables in the `define` snippet. This prevents Make from prematurely expanding the variables, especially those used in the rule recipes. Notably `BUILD_TYPE` and `BUILD_PREFIX` are expanded immediately. If you change the `eval` on the final lines to `warning` you can see the expansion for yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much! I could finally make it work.

Comment: @OrangieLou Check the second approach to see if you like it better.

Comment: The first option is better but you don't have to use MAKELEVEL and if/endif.  Just have the "outer" targets called `release` and `debug` and the "inner" targets called something else, like `sub_release` and `sub_debug`, then when you invoke the sub-make call that target instead, like `$(MAKE) BUILD_TYPE=release sub_release`.  You can even combine these rules into a single static pattern rule if you want.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work the way you want it to:

```
release: BUILD  := $(BUILD)/release
debug: BUILD    := $(BUILD)/debug

$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
```

From [the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) you will see:

> As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments)

That means that target-specific variables cannot be used in the target or prerequisite of rules, since they are only set inside the recipe.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I sort of thought something like this could be the problem. I just know so little about makefiles, I couldn't figure out how to fix it. But now it's solved.